# Why can I not assign this Qt property?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt4, qt5

Qt throws the following error at runtime.

```
Unable to assign LIMITS_T to LIMITS_T
```

I assume that Qt needs more meta data information, but I don't know what I missing. I have done everything to declare the metatype:

**limits.h**

```
class LIMITS_T : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(float min READ readMin WRITE writeMin NOTIFY minChanged)

public:
    LIMITS_T() : QObject() {}
    LIMITS_T(const LIMITS_T& limit) : QObject()
    {
        this->min = limit.min;
    }

    float min = 0;

    float readMin() { return min; }
    void writeMin(float min) { this->min = min; }

    bool operator = (const LIMITS_T &limit)
    {
        this->min = limit.min;
    }

signals:
    void minChanged();
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(LIMITS_T)
```

This is a simplified version of the splitBarGauge class

**splitDialGauge.h**

```
class SplitDialGauge : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(LIMITS_T limits READ getLimits WRITE setLimits NOTIFY limitsChanged)

public:
    SplitDialGauge(QQuickItem *parent = 0);

protected:
    LIMITS_T limits;
    virtual LIMITS_T getLimits();
    virtual void setLimits(LIMITS_T value);
}
```

**splitDialGauge.cpp**

```
#include "splitBarGauge.h"

SplitDialGauge::SplitDialGauge(QQuickItem *parent = 0);
    : QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{
}

LIMITS_T SplitDialGauge::getLimits()
{
    return this->limits;
}

void SplitDialGauge::setLimits(LIMITS_T limits)
{
    this->limits = limits;
    update();
}
```

And I register the class with the Qt Metadata system

```
#include "limits.h"
#include "splitDialGauge.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<SplitDialGauge>("ExampleModule", 1, 0, "SplitDialGauge");
    qmlRegisterType<LIMITS_T>("ExampleModule", 1, 0, "Limits");
    qRegisterMetaType<LIMITS_T>();

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is a snipet from the QML file

```
import ExampleModule 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 480

    SplitDialGauge {
        Limits {
            id: qtyLimits
            min: 4
        }
        height: 200
        width: 50
        limits: qtyLimits
    }
}
```

Comment: It is Qt, Not QT. QT is for Quick Time.

Comment: @InnokentiyAlaytsev Sorry. Fixed that

Comment: I have tried LIMITS_T and it does not throw me that error, I can not use it together with SplitBarGauge because it seems that it is not part of Qt.

Comment: @InnokentiyAlaytsev Now you are being qute.

Comment: I see that you are overwriting the operator =, this must return an object of the same class: `LIMITS_T operator = (const LIMITS_T &limit)
    {
        this->min = limit.min;
        this->caution = limit.caution;
        this->max = limit.max;
        return *this;
    }`

Comment: @eyllanesc Good catch on the operator override. I fixed that but still have the same problem

Comment: Your code is not an [mcve], since it is not verifiable due to SplitBarGauge, improve it and then I can continue to help you.

Comment: @eyllanesc I believe that I have added the additional components that you need. I have also simplified the LIMITS_T class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare the property as a pointer. All QObjects are supposed to be manipulated as pointers, according to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html):

> **No Copy Constructor or Assignment Operator QObject**
>
> has neither a copy
> constructor nor an assignment operator. This is by design. Actually,
> they are declared, but in a private section with the macro
> Q_DISABLE_COPY(). In fact, all Qt classes derived from QObject (direct
> or indirect) use this macro to declare their copy constructor and
> assignment operator to be private. The reasoning is found in the
> discussion on Identity vs Value on the Qt Object Model page.
>
> The main consequence is that you should use pointers to QObject (or to
> your QObject subclass) where you might otherwise be tempted to use
> your QObject subclass as a value. For example, without a copy
> constructor, you can't use a subclass of QObject as the value to be
> stored in one of the container classes. You must store pointers.

In your case:

```
#ifndef SPLITDIALGAUGE_H
#define SPLITDIALGAUGE_H

#include "limits_t.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QQuickPaintedItem>    

class SplitDialGauge : public QQuickPaintedItem {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(LIMITS_T *limits READ getLimits WRITE setLimits NOTIFY limitsChanged)
    LIMITS_T *limits;    
public:
    SplitDialGauge(QQuickItem *parent = 0) : QQuickPaintedItem(parent), limits(nullptr) { }
    void paint(QPainter *painter) {
        [...]
    }    
    LIMITS_T *getLimits() const { return limits; }
    void setLimits(LIMITS_T *value) {
        if (limits == value) return;
        limits = value;
        [...]
        emit limitsChanged();
    }     
signals:
    void limitsChanged();
};
#endif // SPLITDIALGAUGE_H
```

A functional example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/47803531).

Comment: You really want to null the pointer in such cases. Right now it is a dangling reference, it will pass an if statement, and when it is used the program will crash. Also follow the idiomatic way to implement the setter - don't do anything if the new value is the same as the old value. You don't want to emit change notifications without actual changes.